# GCP BQ metric for query count not reflecting correct no

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-monitoring

Recently we faced an outage due to 403 rateLimitExceeded error. We are trying to setup an alert using gcp metric for this error. However the metric for `bigquery.googleapis.com/query/count` or `bigquery.googleapis.com/job/num_in_flight` is not showing the number of queries running correctly. We believe we crossed the threshold of 100 concurrent queries several times over the past few days but the metric explorer shows only a maximum of 5 only on few occasions. Do these metrics need any other configs to show the right number or we should use some other way to create an alert that shows that we have crossed 80% of concurrent query no.

Comment: 5 is very different than 100. Do you know for certain that 5 is wrong? The metrics are usually correct.

Comment: Yes sure about it , checked it again now , showing just max 5 , for global or bq project resource

Comment: I understand that it's only showing 5. Do you know that it is actually doing more? I assume you do, but I'm just trying to make sure.

Comment: Sure, thanks , mainly we got error when there were several select queries executed together. So can you help in finding the exact metric?

Comment: I'm just trying to make sure the metric is incorrect. I think you may be assuming that there are 100 simultaneous queries because of the error, so the metric is wrong. I'm thinking possibly the metric is right and you are getting the error for a different reason.